# Custom template from User Angular2 to replace with default one

Tags: angular, typescript

We can include HTML to component as

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-component',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html', // default html
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
```

I would like to `get the template from the user and replace with the default` one. Something like this.

```
export class AppComponent {
   @Input() customTemplate: TemplateRef;

   // some replacement logic
   // this custom template will replace the default one

}
```

HTML

```
<app [customTemplate]="myTemplate"></app>
<ng-template #myTemplate>
    Hello World!
</ng-template>
```

Comment: You may find answer looking for posts about components with multiple templates

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to replace the default with the new one

Answer (score 0):

You cannot dynamically change templates in Angular. Nor can you set several of them at compile-time.

You could, however, create multiple components with predefined templates, and use some conditional logic to load the correct component (and so, the correct template associated with it) in a fixed container component.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-component',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html', // default html
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent() { /   
    templateNumber: number; // set this to 1 or 2
    // Input or changed by another mean
}


@Component({
    selector: 'first',
    templateUrl: './first.component.html'
})
export class FirstComponent() { /* ... */ }


@Component({
    selector: 'second',
    templateUrl: './second.component.html'
})
export class SecondComponent() { /* ... */ }
```

app.component.html

```
<p>Hello !</p>
<first *ngIf="templateNumber === 1"> </first>
<second *ngIf="templateNumber === 2"> </second>
```